# C++ unable to find method definition from base class

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void a() = 0;
  virtual ~A();
};

class B: public A {
public:
  virtual void b() = 0;
  virtual ~B();
};

class C: public A {
public:
  void a() override {}
};

class D: public B, public C {
  void b() override {}
};

int main(int, char**) {
  B* b = new D();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, however, gcc (4.8.4 from ubuntu 14.04) is unable to find the definition from the base class C for the method A::a() when instantiating an object of type D:

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 test.cc
test.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cc:22:16: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'D'
   B* b = new D();
                ^
test.cc:17:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'D':
 class D: public B, public C {
       ^
test.cc:3:16: note:     virtual void A::a()
   virtual void a() = 0;
```

When I explicitly add A as a base class for D, I get the warning:

```
test.cc:17:7: warning: direct base 'A' inaccessible in 'D' due to ambiguity [enabled by default]
 class D: public A, public B, public C {
       ^
```

I was under the impression that the "dreaded diamond" is applicable only when inheriting from a base class *with data members* on multiple paths.  Am I mistaken?  Or is this supposed to work?

Comment: You have to override `a()` that came in via the B base, or use virtual inheritance.  The `a()` overrider in `C` only overrides on the `A` that is the base of `C`.  E.g. in `D`, `void a() override { }`

Comment: You don't have a diamond inheritance but an **Y**. `D` inherits twice from different `A`.

Comment: @Jarod42 people often say "diamond inheritance" to mean the non-virtual case. (Doesnt make much sense to me but that appears to be common terminology). [Example](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond)

Comment: Ah... so really, we should always use virtual inheritance for interface classes (no data, no constructor, only pure virtual methods), since it doesn't make sense to have them in more than one place in the hierarchy, and it avoids weird corner cases like this.

Comment: Virtual inheritance has its own pitfall (mostly when non default constructor is used).

Comment: It definitely does.  And it increases the overhead when accessing data fields, since it needs to recompute the "this" pointer through the vtable.  But if there are no data fields (or non-virtual functions) and no constructor, I'm not sure what disadvantage there would be.  (leaving aside the NVI discussion)